# PHP function - Order array

Tags: php

Exsists in PHP a function that change the order every time it loops?

```
I used: array_unshift() but it doesn't do the right job
```

Example:

1. 1234 (row 1)
2. 4123 (row 2)
3. 3412 (row 3)
4. 2341 (row 4)

Comment: _that change the order every time it loops_ - The order of _what_?

Comment: Yes, for example if it have in input value: 5 It will loop it five times(Es 12345 -51234-45123-34512-23451)

Comment: Make 2 loops and shuffle the array in the outer loop

Comment: How? I've tried but without any result

Comment: Show us your current code, what it outputs and what you expect to get

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_pop` to pop and get the element off the end of array, and `array_unshift` to prepend it to the beginning of the array, then repeat the process for `$input` iterations.

```
$input = 5;

$digits = range(1, $input);
for ($i=0; $i<$input; $i++) {
    echo implode('', $digits), "\n";
    array_unshift($digits, array_pop($digits));
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9Ic3D).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i have understood you correct but you can try the following:

```
$data = str_split('12345');
$n = 4;
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    echo implode('', $data).'<br />'; //This is for demonstrating purposes
    array_unshift($data, array_pop($data));
}
```

Result:

```
12345
51234
45123
34512
```